# TypeScript Compile Target in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

A few months ago I looked into TypeScript for the first time. I could swear, there was an option in the GUI where I could set the `--target` compiler parameter.

Now it's gone, or at least I can't find it. I guess it has to do with the Visual Studio version. I used the VS2012 back then. Now I'm on VS2013.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously this was possible with Web Essentials in Tools -> Options
 * On the left Web Essentials -> TypeScript and there is a option for ES3 or ES5
This is removed from web essentials see the following blog post: http://madskristensen.net/post/web-essentials-2013-where-is-the-typescript-support

Note: Web Essentials now again has support for TypeScript but changing this setting is now in the TypeScript plugin (and not Web Essentials)

You can find this by right clicking your project and choose "TypeScript build" on the left side. There is a option to change ECMAScript 3 to ECMAScript 5 (among other things).
Also see there blogpost with screenshots about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx

You can also change this manually if you want by editing the csproj. Somewhere in there, there is a PropertyGroup where you can change the TypeScriptTarget, see the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Change it to ES3 if you want to target ECMAScript 3

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty Asp.net web project and added a typescript file (which upgraded the project).  I was pulling out my hair trying to figure out why i didn't have the "TypeScript Build" tab in the project properties.  I closed Visual Studio (2013 Update 2 RC), and when I re-opened the solution, voila, the tab magically appeared.

This stuff is awesome and makes me very happy :) :)  // this is a statement based on opinion ;)